# magento add wysiwyg block to cms page

Tags: magento, content-management-system, wysiwyg, adminhtml, static-block

Using Magento, I need to offer my clients the public use of a wysiwyg editor on my website to simply generate html code for them to copy and paste.  My idea is to add a static block to a cms page... the block being a wysiwyg editor.  Anyone know if it is possible to set up a static block for the wysiwyg editor in Magento?  If so, please explain how this is done in detail.  If you would like more info on why I need this, just ask and I'll get into the details, but I'm hoping for a discussion on how to achieve this, not a discussion on why I need to do this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by thinking outside of the box.

Just used [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) on a CMS page and it works great... does exactly what I need it to do.